# Get Url in post Action of ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, url, razor, http-post

I have 2 Index Actions Post And Get when I submitted form the Post Action returned:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

**Edit:**

My get Index Action can get some parameters to support search and filter returned List. like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string search = "", long searchItem = 0, long RC = 0, long Page = 1)
```

I used Paged List and there is a `DropDownList` that show Numbers of row in per page, I Write a jquery script to change of this dropdown form.submited and when form submitted 
in `RedirectTAction`  I lost my parameters the followings Code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection collection, string search = "") {

    long RowCount = 0;
    long.TryParse(string.Format("{0}", collection["RowCount"]), out RowCount);

//More implement

return RedirectToAction("Index", new { RC = RowCount, search = search, searchItem = Id });
```

So is there any way to Get Url or url parameters in Post Action? What is your suggestion in situations like this?

Comment: What url parameters? Normally when you POST there aren't query string parameters. Or are there in your case? Are you talking about query string parameters or route values or POSTed values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could capture all query string parameters in a RouteValueDictionary before redirecting:

```
var query = new RouteValueDictionary(
    Request
        .QueryString
        .Keys
        .OfType<string>()
        .ToDictionary(key => key, key => (object)Request.QueryString[key])
);
return RedirectToAction("Index", query);
```

This will only keep the query string parameters. If you want to add route values and POSTed values you could concatenate them to the result.

Comment: Thanks, That was really helpful, actually I don't want pass all the Route value as posted, so I use `if(Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains("searchItem")) long.TryParse(Request.QueryString.GetValues("searchItem").FirstOrDefault(), out Id);`